# Xamarin Community Studio: Annoying auto–indentation

Tags: c#, xamarin, monodevelop, xamarin-studio

How do I disable auto-indentation feature/bug? (Xamarin 6.11, Mac)

- Note: <CURSOR HERE> designates position of cursor and not actual code.

Here are my steps:

1. I place my cursor as shown:

[image]

2. I press ENTER:

[image]

3. I type my declaration and jump to beginning hoping to fix indentation:

[image]

4. I press BACKSPACE:

[image]

Pressing ENTER again at this point brings me back to step 3.

Please help, it's driving me nuts!

Oh yes, changing indentation in Preferences->Code Formatting->C# ... does not affect the behavior, even with restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2509/incorrect-auto-formatting-of-c-code-for-specific-functions

Look down to where it says Text Editor -> Behavior.
There is an option named "Enable on the fly code formatting"; You may want to disable this if you wish to format your own codes.

There is also the Smart Indentation mode in Behavior you might want to turn off.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. It was Text Editor -> Behavior -> Indentation -> Backspace removes indentation. Unchecked it mercilessly!